# jquery - preventing user from entering multiple decimal points

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure whats the best way to do this.  In my Ruby on rails app I have numeric textboxes.

They can type in things like 30.5, 30,000, 3,000,000 etc

But how can I prevent them from entering `30.3.1.1.1`, I just want to convert that to 0.

Currently if they type that in a field and tab out of the field, it shows "`Infinity`" in the text field.

Comment: How do you *currently* handle it? Change that code to pit in a zero on blur instead of the result of the conversion.

Comment: If you call "to_f" on the parameter it will use the first decimal point and ignore the rest, which might be a better way to handle this.  `"30.3.1.1.1".to_f => 30.3`

Answer (score 0):

Use Keydown event to read the ASCII code of the character that has been pressed.
Once a `"."` has been entered, set a variable as flag indicating that.
If a "." is pressed another time, just replace the pressed ASCII with *null*.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a regexp which triggers on every keyup - something like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("foo")
input.onkeyup = function(ev){
    input.value = input.value.replace(/([0-9]*\.[0-9]*).*/, "$1")
}
```

Try it out here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8bsx7c9z/

in jQuery it would be something like:

```
var input = $("#foo")
input.on("keyup", function(ev){
    input.val(input.val().replace(/([0-9]*\.[0-9]*).*/, "$1"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Ruby on Rails you can give validation in the model.

```
validates :points, numericality: true
```

For more details you can look to the [document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality).

Comment: I have this already, can it be modified to include true? ................. 

validates :agent_single, numericality: {  less_than_or_equal_to: Proc.new { |a| [a.agent_aggregate, MIN_VALUE].compact.max } }, unless: 'agent_single.blank?'

Comment: What did you actually mean by include true? Can you please clarify your state?

Comment: You want to accept '30.1.3.2' as value & convert it to 0 even when the numericality is true?